# Should I use webKit or is there a better technology to make a browser in Windows

Tags: c++, python, web-applications, desktop-application

I create web applications most in RoR and PHP. About a year ago a company wanted to use my app but in a stand alone browser window in Linux, so I wrote one in python using webkit, locked it down to just accessing the target web app, easily done.

Now what options do I have to do the same for Windows?

I want basic browser functionality such as going back and forward pages and to stop the script from loading. It will have to run stand alone or maybe install via .exe file. Sorry for my ignorance on this but I very rarely enter a Windows Environment.

Comment: python and webkit are both cross-platform, maybe you could see if you can get your previous solution running on windows

Comment: Check out node-webkit on github.  It will let you create standalone desktop apps using HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have pretty much the same options, actually. WebKit is cross-platform, as are other browser engines.

Also, I'd think that quite a lot of general purpose mainstream programming languages would already provide a "WebView" component that should be good enough for most use cases.

For instance, Java has had this capability for quite a long while. Though I'd expect it wasn't rocket fast for the time and would scream for its mommy with the amount of JS that's now present in most web-apps; but surely that must have improved as well over time.

Android has such a WebView, that pretty much allows to invoke the Android Browser (not sure what happens now that newer versions have switched to Chrome for Android, actually; I don't know if that view now relies on a stripped view of the legacy browser or or the mobile Chrome one).

.NET has a similar capability to invoke the same components as the ones used by IE.

And so on.

But if your thing is done with Python and WebKit and some graphic toolkit, I'd be surprised if you can't get it to run on Windows as well.

Comment: "WebKit" may be "cross-platform" but it is certainly nowhere near the same quality on Linux/Windows as it is on Mac.

Comment: @Steven: Maybe, though the OP makes no comment on the level of support and quality he intends to achieve, and we don't know if it's for internal use or release. So that may not be an issue at all.

Comment: Not sure what Java component you're talking about. There are third party solutions to embed browser engines, but what comes with the language (JEditorPane) is absolutely primitive - supports HTML 3.2, a subset of CSS, and no JS at all (I don't think it even has a DOM).

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: Yes, it's very primitive (and slow). There used to be as well [JDIC](http://javadesktop.org/articles/jdic/) that provided some capabilities for that (although also quite primitive, or maybe even based on the same, I don't remember specifics). There's also [DJ](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html), and the [Browser](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-browser-widget/browser.html) widget embedded in the Eclipse platform which resorts to your platform's engine of choice.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: Amongst the most recent, you have JavaFX's [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) and its [WebEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html). That's some options at least. Anyways, I don't think OP is interested in this route, it was just an example of a language with support. It's easy to pick on the old basic component in the JRE, it was here more than a decade ago, and at the time it was still pretty cool :)